# Laravel 7 migration: Syntax error or access violation: 1068 Multiple primary key defined

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7, laravel-migrations, mysql-error-1068

When I try to do `php artisan migrate` it gives me this error
`Illuminate\Database\QueryException`:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1068 Multiple primary key defined (SQL: alter table `users` add primary key `users_user_id_primary`(`user_id`))

I'm pretty new to Laravel, tho

Here are my migrations:

User migration

```
    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id('user_id')->primary();
        $table->string('username')->unique();
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
    });
}
```

Post migration

```
    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id('post_id');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->string('content');
        $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained();
        $table->primary(['post_id', 'user_id']); 


    });
}
```

Categories migration

```
    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id('id_cat')->primary();
        $table->string('nom');
        
    });
}
```

Marques migration

```
    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('marques', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id('marque_id');
        $table->foreignId('cat_id')->constrained();
        $table->string('designation');
        $table->primary(['marque_id','cat_id']); 
    });
}
```

UserMarques migration

```
    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('user_marques', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreignId('cat_id')->constrained();
        $table->foreignId('marque_id')->constrained();
        $table->timestamps();
    $table->primary(['marque_id','user_id']); 
    });
}
```

Comment: Remove `primary()` and leave just `id()`. Le: `$table->id('user_id');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$table->increments('user_id');` instead of `$table->id('user_id')->primary();`

and with others.

BTW, i prefer only id instead of with model name, so in this case i prefer this:
`$table->increments('id');`

**Update for Laravel 7.x**

Laravel 7.x migration comes with id method

```
public function id($column = 'id')
{
    return $this->bigIncrements($column);
}
```

so in this case: you can use id like this

```
$table->id();
```

PS: increments key comes with primary key

Comment: oh but whats dif between increments and id ?

Comment: id come with laravel 7, id supplies to you bigIncrement, and this is also ok. I will update my answer